# Design Item ID standardization

Tags: circuit-design, standard

I am wondering whether there is a solid standard on how to give components an unique identifier. In Altium it is called a Design Item ID, and in our company we used it as a unique identifier on the ERP and our whole workflow (design, purchasing, manufacturing, testing, servicing etc.) used that ID in order to distinguish components. It is packaging ignorant, so same for tube, tray, tape.

It is a de-facto standard which is homebrew. (for example, IPC doesn't have one AFAIK.) In my old company, it would be something like this:

- IND205101029 - An common mode choke from Würth, hence IND for inductor.
- ICTJF1051T31 - A CAN Transciever from NXP , TJF1051

and so on. Many times this code incorporates some key parameters like values like resistance, inductance, or would have modifiers for AEC qualification for automotive parts, industrial temperature range or flexible terminations.

I am wondering whether I have to devise my N+1 th standard that fits me now but will probably wear out in a decade? ([Obligatory XKCD?](https://xkcd.com/927/))

Right now I am wondering whether I can just use someone else's code which needs to put so much more time in this that I can just rely on them? I was thinking I could use the Digikey order number for this unique identifier. I know that it is incomprehensible, but it is at least a solution for a problem.

My question might sound like a poll (I hope that I was able to express that this is a design standardization question, I am sure that there is an industry best practice out there that I don't know.), but I really feel the need to hear the best standards in this.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the "Design Item ID" or Library Part Number as is more commonly known, was usually defined by the ERP system, as this one is usually the one with the most limitations in terms of flexibility.

In most companies I have worked for, the parts usually has a type identifier such as Res, Cap, Ind, and then a sequential number. The fact that is is just a number didn't create problems when searching for parts in the library, as Altium allows you to search with wildcards even in the description field, so looking for a 10k resistor was a walk in the park. The advantage of using a sequential number, and a simple type prefix, is that it makes it easy to keep consistency between users. The only issue I have found is that the part has to be created first in the ERP system, as that one should be the only authority to release unique part numbers, in order to avoid caos.

Slightly off topic, is a neat feature of Altium that allows you to query the information out of an ERP system through ODBC queries. In this way you just need to type the data once into the ERP, and there is no need to repeat it into the Altium library.

Comment: Thank you for sharing, this is indeed a solution, and a good one. But it requires a thorough check that a component is not double defined. Also, my company standardized the E24 chip resistors, and sales would buy them from a wide range of suppliers, which makes the association one-to-many rather than one-to-one.

Answer (score 1):

This is a really interesting aspect and something I am currently grappling with at a new company. We are looking at using part prefix followed by primary criteria for a part and a variant specifier. e.g A capacitor might be C-100N-50V-X7R-0805-T03 or a resistor R-2k2-W25-0402-T01.

The variant specifier is used to discriminate between say surge rated resistors, or different qualifications or Reach status etc. The primary criteria obviously differs between part types. The internal part number/Design Item ID/ERP part number are all one in the same. As this part number is describing the characteristics of the part (in part;) then I feel the PCB master library would be the master.

I'm not excited about the Digikey style as it adds no intrinsic value / identification.

Comment: This is an old thread, but still something that I haven't got a good solution for. I get the need for intrinsic value, but when it comes to ever developing market of components, the "schema" of that value is often subject to frequent change, which is not easy to handle.